# Why should we define a scope of a dependency in Maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies

Maven provides a  tag for dependencies which can "limit the transitivity of a dependency". I understand, that by defining, for instance, a test scope for a given dependency, this dependency will not be available in other phases (diagram). But I don't get what is the advantage of doing so?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Scopes have three main purposes:

- avoid that you use something in your application that you did not want to use (if you declare the implementation as `runtime`, you cannot accidentally use it in your code).
- reduce the amount of transitive dependencies. Especially `test` dependencies will not become dependencies of the users of your library.
- reduce the size of a WAR/EAR: If your container already provides the dependencies, you declares them as `provided` so that they are not packaged into your application.

Answer (score 1):

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope

You don't need hoe and gun for digging, you just need hoe only.

You don't need JUnit dependency for running on web-server (scope `runtime`), you need JUnit when you test only (scope `test`), you don't need JUnit when you package for production.

Another benefit is avoiding version conflicting, avoid unnecessary dependencies redundancy.